# Knockout Nested Bindings--Visible in DOM but won't display

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, requirejs

I've got an issue where my viewmodel has an observable object that contains observable properties.  When I try to access those properties they don't display.  I can, however, see that all the properties with values are visible in the DOM using the Knockout chrome extension.

My code looks like:

viewmodel:

```
self.device=ko.observable();       
self.device(querydevice.query({"url": self.url, "ref":self.ref}));
```

query code:

```
define(['jquery','knockout','hsd'], function ($,ko, device) {
return{ 
query:function (params) {
        var hsdevice=ko.observable();   
        self.url=params.url;
        self.ref=params.ref;
        var controlData = $.getJSON(self.url + "/JSON?request=getcontrol&ref=" + self.ref);
        var statusData = $.getJSON(self.url + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + self.ref);
        $.when(controlData, statusData).done(function (_cdata, _sdata) {
            var data = $.extend(_cdata[0], _sdata[0]);
            hsdevice(new device(data));              
        });

        return hsdevice;
    }};
});
```

device object:

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

return function device (data){
    var self=this;
    self.deviceName = ko.observable(data.Devices[0].name);
    self.value = ko.observable(data.Devices[0].value);
    self.status =ko.observable(data.Devices[0].status);
    self.controlPairs = ko.observableArray();
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.controlPairs, data.ControlPairs);

     };
});
```

This is what I see being returned:

```
" device": Object
controlPairs: Array[2]
deviceName: "Garage Hall Light"
status: "Off"
value: 0
```

In my HTML I have this:

```
<span class="tile-title align-" data-bind="with: device.deviceName"></span>
```

I've also tried using data-bind:"text: device().deviceName", but that doesn't work either.  Nothing displays.  I can however access over observable properties that are on the viewmodel.  The only difference is that they're single level properties with no sub-binding.  So I am able to see something like self.test("test") in my html but not my self.device with the nested databinds.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using jquery promises.  what you need to do is return the `$.when`

something like

```
define(['jquery','knockout','hsd'], function ($,ko, device) {
return{ 
query:function (params) {   
        self.url=params.url;
        self.ref=params.ref;
        var controlData = $.getJSON(self.url + "/JSON?request=getcontrol&ref=" + self.ref);
        var statusData = $.getJSON(self.url + "/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=" + self.ref);
        return $.when(controlData, statusData).done(function (_cdata, _sdata) {
            var data = $.extend(_cdata[0], _sdata[0]);
            return new device(data);              
        });
    }};
});
```

then you end up with something like this.

```
querydevice.query({"url": self.url, "ref":self.ref})
.when(function(data){
   self.device(data);
   return true;
});
```

Comment: Hi Nathan...thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, after making those suggested changes, "device" is now undefined when I look at it using the Kockout debugger in chrome after the page has rendered.  At least with my previous code, "device" had the properties and values I was expecting, I just couldn't get them to display for whatever reason. Any idea why "device" would now come back as undefined?

Comment: Actually disregard the previous statement.  I didn't have "querydevice.query(xxx).when.... correct.  But even with that changes made I now get:  "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" at the "querydevice.query" call.   Any idea what would cause this error?

Comment: I made the following change which now returns data back to the DOM, but now I'm back to the original problem of the data not being visible in the HTML via data-binding:              $.when(querydevice.query({"url": self.url, "ref":self.ref})).done(function(data){
            self.device(data[0].Devices[0]);
            return true;
        });

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nathan for his code contribution.  I was finally able to access my nested properties in the html by using:

```
<!-- ko with: device -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

and THEN data-bind to the property I needed.

Comment: I also needed to use: return $.when(controlData, statusData).then(function (_cdata, _sdata).  The key was THEN instead of DONE.